# Are there any predefined functions that implement the Gauss and the Jacobi algorithms in Python?

Tags: python

I am looking for predefined functions that implement in Python the Gauss and the Jacobi methods for solving linear equations. Are there any or I must write them myself?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych yes, I did. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question here.

Comment: Something like this for the Jacobi? https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Jacobi-Method-in-Python-and-NumPy/

Comment: I don't think so. At least not in python cores predefined functions. There are some functions in _numpy_ to calculate the eigenvalue using LAPACK. But I doubt anyone uses Gaussian and Jacobian methods these days. They are not particularly general and there are some cases in which the algorithm breaks down. Might I ask why do you need it?

Comment: @ARK1375 I am updating an university numerical methods course and I use Python.

Comment: Then I think you are better of implementing it yourself. It should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: have a look on following link it impliments154
https://github.com/lathestudent/Direct-and-Iterative-Solver-of-Linear-Systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. At least not in python cores predefined functions. There are some functions in NumPy to calculate the eigenvalue using LAPACK. But I doubt anyone uses Gaussian and Jacobian methods these days. They are not particularly general and there are some cases in which the algorithm breaks down.
On the other hand, there are various implementations on the internet that you can use if you want.
Here are some examples:
Link 1: [Gausian Implementation](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Jacobi-Method-in-Python-and-NumPy/)
Link 2: [Jacobian Implementation No.1](https://gist.github.com/4137321)
Link 3: [Jacobian Implementation No.2](https://www.programmersought.com/article/78574323800/)

Comment: Thnk you very much!